# 'ir' and 'vamos' in one sentence

Tags: verbos

I am studying Spanish with the *Michel Thomas' Method*. It lists the following:

> We will go see it. / Vamos a ir a verlo.
>      We will go / Iremos
>      We will go see it. / Iremos a verlo.

For the first example, why is **ir** used? Thought **ir** means **to go** and **vamos a** means **we will go**.
So by using them both, isn't that saying

> We will go go and see it

Could someone explain why both **ir** and **vamos** are used in the same sentence?

Comment: "Vamos a ir a verlo" would be better translated as "we are going to go see it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ir* plays triple duty, being used to construct the periphrastic future, to indicate motion, and occasionally to construct *nosotros<sub>/as</sub>* commands.  Only two of these three are mutually exclusive, so we get two potential interpretations with *vamos a ir a ver*.

The first *ir* can either set up the future or, thanks to being specifically the form *vamos* (a shortened form of *vayamos*), it can also substitute as a command, equivalent to English's “let’s…”.

In either case, the second *ir* expresses the actual action which is to go.

You might be think that since both *ir*s are followed by *a* that they are both expressing future and that your main verb is *ver*, but just because something is *ir a [verbo]* doesn't mean it's a periphrastic future construction.

Consider:

> Vamos a tomar el metro para poder llegar al cine para ver la película
>
> Vamos a tomar el metro para ir al cine para ver la película.
>
> Vamos a ir en metro al cine para ver la película.
>
> Vamos a ir al cine a ver la película.
>
> Vamos a ir a ver la película
>
> Iremos a ver *(future sense)*
> Vayamos a ver *(command sense)*

The *a* is really a *para* in disguise showing purpose, but not necessarily temporality.

Answer (score 2):

*we will go see it* is translated as *iremos a verlo*.

*vamos a ir a verlo* is translated as the following forms:

> let's go see it.
>
> we're going to go see it.

*vamos* and *ir* are different.
To use *vamos* we usually use *let's go...* or *we're going...* depending of how we want to express ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

The Present Tense in Spanish is remarkable as it can be used to express things in the Present, Past and Future.

One such format by which to express a future event using the Present Tense is:

```
"Ir(conj.) + a + Infinitive"
```

such as

```
  "Voy a leer mio libro."
   I am going to read my book.
```

Your example expression:

```
  "Vamos a ir a verlo."
```

is using this format by which the Present Tense 'vamos', we are going/we go, is being used to express something that will be done in the future 'a verlo'... to see it.

```
  We are going(will be going)  to see it.
```

We are going is Present Tense but it's talking about the Future.

There is a similar format by which the Present Tense can be used to talk about a recent past event with the format:

```
 "Acabar de + Infinitive"
```

such as:

```
 "Acabo de escribir mi respuesto."
  I just finished writing my answer.
```

Fun.